# How do I run 2 or more functions when using 'onclick'?

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, onclick

I want to run 2 functions when I press this button. However, only the function "HeadsorTails" is being executed.
 `<button class="coin" onclick="HeadsorTails()" onclick="Restart()">`
Is it even possible to run 2 functions when using onclick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for better reading and debugging you can put your functions in another function:

```
<button class="coin" onclick="doFunctions()">
```

js code:

```
var doFunctions = function() 
{
 HeadsorTails();
 Restart();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply type: `onclick="HeadsorTails(); Restart();"`

Answer (score 0):

For more complex logic, it is better to use `addEventListener` instead of inline event handlers.

```
const btn = document.querySelector('button.coin');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
     HeadsorTails(); 
     Restart();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have multiple functions in a button click

```
<button class="coin" onclick="HeadsorTails();Restart()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could execute the function**s** in one seperate function.

```
function buttonFunc() {
   HeadsorTails()
   Restart()
}


<button class="coin" onclick="buttonFunc()">
```

I believe this way makes it simpler to edit your function later on and it seperate concerns (opinion).